# Gentoo ebuild for CUPS to support Kyocera 1x2x MFP printers

Tags: bash, ebuild

*Let me be the first one to post a Gentoo ebuild for review, as suggested by [this meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8409/) post answer and comments. See also the [corresponding issue](https://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=627802) on Gentoo Bugzilla.*

The ebuild installs proprietary PPDs and Cups filter for Kyocera 1x2x MPF printers, it works on my machine. (Unfortunately, I can only test a single model, not all of them.)

```bash
# Copyright 1999-2017 Gentoo Foundation
# Distributed under the terms of the GNU General Public License v2

EAPI=6

DESCRIPTION="Printer descriptions (PPDs) and filters for Kyocera 1x2x MFP"
HOMEPAGE="http://www.kyoceramita.it/"
SRC_URI="LinuxDrv_${PV}_FS-1x2xMFP.zip"

LICENSE="kyocera-mita-ppds"
SLOT="0"

# TODO: Someone please test the ebuild on ~x86.
KEYWORDS="-* ~amd64 ~x86"

IUSE_LINGUAS=(ar cs de el en es fr he hu it ko pl pt ro ru th tr vi zh_CN zh_TW)
IUSE="+rastertokpsl-fix ${IUSE_LINGUAS[@]/#/linguas_}"
REQUIRED_USE="|| ( ${IUSE_LINGUAS[@]/#/linguas_} )"

RDEPEND="net-print/cups"
DEPEND="app-arch/unzip"
RESTRICT="fetch"

S="${WORKDIR}/Linux"

function archSubdirectory {
    if use x86 && ! use amd64
    then echo "32bit"
    else echo "64bit" ; fi
}

function languageArchiveName {
    # Note the capitalisation inconsistency. Don't "fix" that.
    case "$1" in
        ar)    echo arabic      ;;
        cs)    echo czech       ;;
        de)    echo German      ;;
        el)    echo greek       ;;
        en)    echo English     ;;
        es)    echo Spanish     ;;
        fr)    echo French      ;;
        he)    echo hebrew      ;;
        hu)    echo hungarian   ;;
        it)    echo Italian     ;;
        ko)    echo Korean      ;;
        pl)    echo polish      ;;
        pt)    echo Portuguese  ;;
        ro)    echo romanian    ;;
        ru)    echo russian     ;;
        th)    echo thai        ;;
        tr)    echo turkish     ;;
        vi)    echo vietnamese  ;;
        zh_CN) echo simplified  ;;
        zh_TW) echo traditional ;;
    esac
}

pkg_nofetch() {
    einfo "Please, navigate your browser to the following URL and manually"
    einfo "download the file named '$A', then put it into '$DISTDIR'."
    einfo "http://www.kyoceradocumentsolutions.eu/index/service/dlc.false.driver.FS1025MFP._.EN.html"
    einfo ""
    einfo "Consider keeping a local copy of the file since there're chances"
    einfo "the company is going to eventually stop hosting it for whatever"
    einfo "reason."
}

src_prepare() {
    eapply_user

    function patchFilterPath {
        local orig="/usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertokpsl"
        local repl="/usr/libexec/cups/filter/rastertokpsl"
        use rastertokpsl-fix &&
            repl="${repl}-fix.sh"

        sed -i "s|$orig|$repl|g" "$@"
    }

    local g="$S/$(archSubdirectory)/Global"
    local lingua
    for lingua in "${IUSE_LINGUAS[@]}"; do
        use linguas_$lingua || continue

        local language="$(languageArchiveName "$lingua")"

        unpack "$g/$language.tar.gz"
        patchFilterPath "$language"/Kyocera*.ppd

        # The upstream contains a number of files named 'rastertokpsl',
        # each having the same content.
        mv --no-clobber "$language/rastertokpsl" "$S/rastertokpsl"
    done

    if use rastertokpsl-fix; then
        cp "$FILESDIR"/rastertokpsl-fix.sh .
    fi
}

src_install() {

    function installWithLinguaSuffix {
        local lingua="$1"; shift
        for file in "$@"; do
            local dn="$(dirname "$file")"
            local bn="$(basename "$file" .ppd)"
            newins "$dn/$bn.ppd" "${bn}_$lingua.ppd"
        done
    }

    insinto /usr/share/cups/model/KyoceraMita
    local lingua
    for lingua in "${IUSE_LINGUAS[@]}"; do
        use linguas_$lingua || continue

        local language="$(languageArchiveName "$lingua")"
        installWithLinguaSuffix "$lingua" \
            "$language"/Kyocera*.ppd
    done

    exeinto /usr/libexec/cups/filter
    doexe rastertokpsl
    use rastertokpsl-fix &&
        doexe rastertokpsl-fix.sh

    dodoc "Readme.htm"

    einfo "This packages installs Kyocera's 'Readme.htm' file (see package"
    einfo "documentation directory) which lists several common problems and"
    einfo "workarounds. You might want to have a look on it."
}
```

Please, tell me about anything you find wrong or suspicious in regard to both bash scripting or established Gentoo practices. However, I would be grateful if you answer some of the below (metaphysical) questions:

1. Is someone interested in this ebuild being in the main tree? Does somebody else uses these buggy printers? *(opinion based)*
2. Did I choose the correct name for the package? Are PPDs, technically, "drivers"?
3. Is it okay to use `IUSE_LINGUAS` as a list, not a string?
4. How should I deal with the situation when user have no `LINGUAS` set, or their language are not supported by the upstream package?
5. I used `function blah {` syntax instead `blah() {` for may helper functions (not build phases, though). Is it acceptable?
6. Is it okay to declare top-level functions at all?
7. Should I put the wrapper script `rastertokpsl-fix.sh` into `files/`, or just create it during `src_prepare` with `echo`?

Comment: I don't know much about make, however you've stylized the code in the question as bash. Is this by any chance a bash script rather than a make script?

Comment: @Peilonrayz: [tag:makefile] was the closest tag I was able to find. Changed it to newly created [tag:ebuild] tag.

Answer (score 1):

I can only comment on the Bash part.

> 3. Is it okay to use `IUSE_LINGUAS` as a list, not a string?

You mean array. The answer will come down to whether it's ok to use Bash.
Arrays have been supported in Bash for a very long time,
only obsolete systems would use such version that doesn't support arrays.

> 5. I used `function blah {` syntax instead `blah() {` for may helper functions (not build phases, though). Is it acceptable?

The script has a mixture of both styles.
That's clearly not good.
It would be better to stick to one style consistently.
The `blah() {` is recommended in Bash.

You can safely replace this:

```
for file in "$@"; do
```

With the simpler:

```
for file; do
```

Because `"$@"` is the default value used by `for in` loops.